# A little trouble with g++ compiling makefile

Tags: c++, makefile, linker, g++

I've got the following `makefile`:

```
test_containers: containers.o
    g++ out/containers.o test/test_containers.cpp -o out/test_containers.exe

containers.o: queue.o stack.o container.o
    g++ -c out/queue.o out/stack.o out/container.o -o out/containers.o

queue.o: container.o
    g++ -c src/Queue.cpp out/container.o -o out/queue.o

stack.o: container.o
    g++ -c src/Stack.cpp out/container.o -o out/stack.o

container.o:
    g++ -c src/Container.cpp -o out/container.o
```

***The problem*** is, when I do `make containers.o`, out/containers.o does not appear.

Compile log:

```
D:\DevProjects\2nd-semester\cpp\S1_dev>make containers.o
g++ -c src/Container.cpp -o out/container.o

g++ -c src/Queue.cpp out/container.o -o out/queue.o
g++: warning: out/container.o: linker input file unused because linking not done

g++ -c src/Stack.cpp out/container.o -o out/stack.o
g++: warning: out/container.o: linker input file unused because linking not done

g++ -c out/queue.o out/stack.o out/container.o -o out/containers.o
g++: warning: out/queue.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
g++: warning: out/stack.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
g++: warning: out/container.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
```

Is there something that I do not understand right? How do I get a containers.o file?

(ran on Windows 10 machine btw)

upd: information supply because people say there's *very* little

My file tree:

```
│   makefile
│
├───.vscode
│       settings.json
│
├───out
│       container.o
│       queue.o
│       stack.o
│
├───src
│       Container.cpp
│       Container.h
│       Queue.cpp
│       Queue.h
│       Stack.cpp
│       Stack.h
│
└───test
        catch.hpp
        test_containers.cpp
```

I don't really know what I can say more other than that .cpp files include matching .h files, and both Queue.h and Stack.h include Container.h and test_containers.cpp file includes catch.

Comment: That isn't the only problem. Most of those rules erroneously have object code from other target rules that don't belong there.`out/container.o` is the most common error. Also, from what I see, `containers.o` should be a static lib file, and have a different recipe to build it. The `test_containers` target should consume that lib, build the test_containers.cpp file and produce the final executable.

Comment: Regarding the question asked, please read the documentation for the gnu compiler's [`-c` option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#index-c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your recipes are cluttered with files that don't belong there. Given the *very* limited amount of information you've provided, the most direct solution is to just slam out the recipes directly.

```
test_containers: out/test_containers.exe

out/test_containers.exe: out/test_containers.o out/containers.a
    g++ $^ -o $@ 

out/test_containers.o: test/test_containers.cpp
    g++ -c $< -o $@

out/containers.a: out/queue.o out/stack.o out/container.o
    ar rcs $@ $^

out/queue.o: src/Queue.cpp
    g++ -c $< -o $@

out/stack.o: src/Stack.cpp
    g++ -c $< -o $@

out/container.o: src/Container.cpp
    g++ -c $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f out/*.o
```

Some notes about some of the stuff you see up there, that make the rules simpler to write:

- `$@` is a macro denoting the target of the rule
- `$^` is a macro that expands to *all* dependencies of the current target, with duplicate names removed.
- `$<` is a macro that expands to the *first* dependency.

There is a LOT more that can/should be done (dependency generation, implicit rule usage, phony target, etc.), but that's the basics of it.

Comment: THANKS a lot for the macros, I didn't even think that makefile could be written that way. I added more information, plus, you solved the problem I was dealing with with `ar rcs`.